# Trigger code not working in oracle to avoid duplicate data

Tags: sql, oracle

Below trigger code(converted from MSSQL) in oracle is not working.

The two columns should not have duplicate row in the table. I'm creating a trigger for accomplishing this.

Can anyone help in updating/correcting the above code to be used in my trigger?

```
/*
**Unique Constraint for TestOracle - TestTinyInt.
*/
if (Update(UpdOperation) or Update(TestTinyInt)) THEN 
                IF Exists(
                                SELECT * FROM inserted i INNER LOOP JOIN TestOracle x ON 
                                                (i.TestTinyInt=x.TestTinyInt)
                                WHERE i.updoperation IN (0, 1) AND x.updoperation IN (0, 1) GROUP BY x.TestTinyInt
                                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
                BEGIN
                                RAISERROR( 'Invalid attempt to enter duplicate TestTinyInt in TestOracle', 16, -1 )
                                ROLLBACK TRAN
                                RETURN
                END
END
```

Comment: Could you explain it a little more? You have one Table and 2 columns, and from this 2 columns they should not have 2 exact same values ? Is this correct?

Comment: Why don't you just use a unique index? That will be **way** more efficient

Comment: There is no such thing as an `INNER LOOP JOIN`

Comment: @hakobot yes 1 table and 2 columns and should not have any duplicate row....i want to create and use trigger for that hence started writing the code...can you help in fixing the code?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i want to use a trigger for the same as i have some more logic too to implement along with this in a trigger....i just need to fix this code to work in my trigger...can you please help?

Comment: The trigger will not see data from concurrent transactions, so this will not work reliably.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create 2 unique index on each of columns. By doing this you are eliminating duplication in particual column(like @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned).

For other case you don't need to use triger, you need only simple where condition

```
where Column_A not in (select Column_B from table) and Column_B not in (Select Column_A in table).
```

EDIT:
It if have to be done in trigger THEN :

```
  create or replace trigger ... instead of insert or update on ...
    Declare
    dummy number;
    Begin
     select 1 into dummy from dual where :new.Column_A in  (select Column_B from table) or new:.Column_B in (Select Column_A in table);
    if dummy <> 1 THEN 
      INSERT 
    END IF;
    END;
```

EDIT2: IF you don't want unique index and tirgger here is solution :

```
 create or replace trigger ... instead of insert or update on ...
    Declare
    dummy number;
    Begin
    select count(*)  into dummy from( 
    SELECT COL1 FROM (
    (select :new.Column_A col1 from  dual  
      UNION 
    select :new.Column_B from dual))
   INTERSECT 
    SELECT COL2 FROM (         
   ( SELECT COLUMN_A COL2 from table 
       UNION
    SELECT COLUMN_B from table));

    if dummy = 0 THEN 
      INSERT 
    END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name....thanks for sharing the index...but i just need this trigger code working for me....if possible please help

Comment: @hakobot...thanks for helping..however i need this trigger code to be working...and accomplish it via trigger...please help there...need it to be CONVERTED..

Comment: @hakobot..again thanks..but still my issue is not solved as you are suggesting of a new trigger code or indexes etc...however what i was looking out for is to just fix the above trigger code...thats it...specially "if exists" etc

Comment: @rock_techie The problem is that i have no idea what kind of code is yours. I don't know how it's working(or even if it working) :) I have never seen "INNER LOOP JOIN", and i doubt is there somethings like this. This is reason why i have written my own code.  Regards

Comment: @hakobot...thanks...this code was converted from mssql to oracle.... can anyone else help in just converting this trigger?

Comment: Why are you so fixated on a trigger? Especially when it has been pointed out that using a trigger in this fashion is fundamentally unreliable,no matter how much you "fix" it.  Keep in mind that Oracle is not just SQL Server with a different label. They are fundamentally different, especially in regards to concurrency and transaction control. Best practice in one is often worst practice in the other.  This is a classic XY problem:  http://xyproblem.info/